# Restriction in XML Schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I need to place a restriction on an integer that can take values between 1 and 48, but can also take the single value of 63. Can this be done?

I know the following will take care of the first restriction, but how can I add 63 to the list?

```
    <xs:simpleType name="nameId">
      <xs:element name="id">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
            <xs:minInclusive value="1"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="48"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Answer (score 2):

Define two types: one allows an integer in the range 1-48, and one that only allows the integer 64; then define a type that is the union of these two.

Or in XSD 1.1, just define a type that restricts xs:integer with the facet

`<assert test="$value=(1 to 48, 64)"/>`

Comment: Thank you, Michael. Is the complete statement something like this: <sch: assert test="$value=(1 to 48, 64)"/>

Comment: Thank you, Michael - I need this statement at the top of the schema , right? <sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://www.ascc.net/xml/schematron"> And then, I should have <sch: assert test="$value=(1 to 48, 64)"/> followed by </assert>?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an integer base you could use a RegEx?

For example this would almost work but it has a caveat....

```
   <xs:simpleType name="nameId">
      <xs:element name="id">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="([1-4]{1}\d|63)"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, Craig. So, I cannot simply add a enumeration like      <xs:simpleType name="svId">
      <xs:element name="id" >
         <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer" >
 <xs:minInclusive value="1">
 <xs:maxInclusive value="48">
      <xs:enumeration value="63">
    <xs:restriction>
          <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:element>
    </xs:simpleType>

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can simply use enumeration with all values you need and have base as integer

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
      <xs:enumeration value="1"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="2"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="3"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="4"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="5"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="6"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="7"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="8"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="9"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="10"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="11"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="12"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="13"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="14"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="15"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="16"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="17"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="18"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="19"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="20"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="21"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="22"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="23"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="24"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="25"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="26"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="27"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="28"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="29"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="30"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="31"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="32"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="33"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="34"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="36"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="36"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="37"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="38"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="39"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="40"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="41"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="42"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="43"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="44"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="45"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="46"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="47"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="48"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="63"/>
    </xs:restriction>
```